# Clickable text in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to have a label with clickable text, I read answers here suggesting FancyLabel.
Is there some new alternative to it?
I know I could also use UIWebView for that but that would be to slow, is there some better way to achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` on it, then add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UILabel` to detect when someone taps on it.

If you want only part of the text to be clickable, then you're going to have to do a lot more work and would probably want to be a completely custom view which handles all of the business logic for doing something that complex.

Comment: Or subclass UILabel, set userInteractionEnabled, and implement touchesBegan:withEvent:. Or make it a custom UIButton and draw text on top.

Comment: ok, I expect some new library or sample code, I used Three20 in the past but it was a big library to use just for that feature.