# How can i implement "more button" like this picture

Tags: ios, uibutton

How can i implement "more button" like this picture (the button will stick with last word of line) . That will take get action when i click at the button (like switch to other view).

Image link
http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/xEYgoqRBMZm5uc23

Comment: Using a simple button with appropriate text would do it.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541676/ios-uitextview-or-uilabel-with-clickable-links-to-actions ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `UIButton`, set the text correctly, and then when the user clicks it you can resize the textview.

Comment: yes perfect. nice answer