# How to show two separate links on different Strings in UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Please look at the below image, Red Color Texts are two different strings and Ash color String are another string. I concatenate those strings into one String and i assigned that string into UILabel.

i used NSMutableAttributedString for applying colors and Font styles to NSString

Now i need to show two separate Links on the Red Color Strings " SIVASAGAR" and "THE ORDER:1886",  when user clicks on that links, it redirects to different views.

Is it possible to achieve this type of scenario using UIButton or STTweetlabel or something else?

NOTE: All the names ,i mean Red Color Strings Positions(X and Y values) will change Dynamically according to requirement.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS UITextView or UILabel with clickable links to actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541676/ios-uitextview-or-uilabel-with-clickable-links-to-actions)

Comment: Is that a new requirement? this function has been implemented in lot of places, you are doing the same job just detecting a link in UILabel. Just you have to customize it according to your need but the function remain same and that you can do it from the following Question link. But I have a big doubt whether you have gone through the answer? Or you may be wanting a ready-made solution then that is different .

Comment: Why you can't put your link in two lines? With this kind of thinking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedtext-of-a-uilabel/29352519#29352519, detecting the range should help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `UITextView` and add:

```
[attributedText addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"yourCustomSchemeUrl://" range:linkRange];
```

and implement Custom URL Scheme

Comment: By using UITextview is it possible to achieve my task?

Comment: if i do like above, then clickable link will expand into two lines?