# Turn some parts of UILabel to act like a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I have an attributed string `UILabel`, I was able to color some parts of the text

```
let text = "Why did \(event) give \(event2) a 5 stars review? Details here. "
let linkTextWithColor = "Why did"
let range = (text as NSString).rangeOfString(linkTextWithColor)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blackColor() , range: range)

labelEvent.attributedText = attributedString
```

Now I want to make some parts of the text tappable, like a `UIButton`, how to do this ?

Example 1

[image: example 1]

Example 2

[image: example 2]

I need to have blue text to be responding to touch, and to run a specific function, like a `UIButton`.
help is really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to a couple solutions, I didn't want to take credit :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541676/ios-uitextview-or-uilabel-with-clickable-links-to-actions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629784/make-a-clickable-link-in-an-nsattributedstring-for-a-uitextfield-or-uilabel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedtext-of-a-uilabel look at once

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you try this library out

https://github.com/null09264/FRHyperLabel

Great library, easy to use and has few built in examples for you to try out. Examples are in both Objective-c and Swift

Example in Swift

```
 let str = "This is a random bit of text"
        let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
                          NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)]
        confirmLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attributes)

        let handler = {
            (hyperLabel: FRHyperLabel!, substring: String!) -> Void in

            //action here
        }
        //Step 3: Add link substrings
        confirmLabel.setLinksForSubstrings(["random"], withLinkHandler: handler)
```

Edit:

If you want to get rid of the underline, best way to do this is to follow the advice that DeyaEldeen gave in the comment.

If you go to the .m file of FRHyperLabel, go to this method

```
- (void)checkInitialization {
    if (!self.handlerDictionary) {
        self.handlerDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }

    if (!self.userInteractionEnabled) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

    if (!self.linkAttributeDefault) {
        self.linkAttributeDefault = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: FRHyperLabelLinkColorDefault,
                                      NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};
    }

    if (!self.linkAttributeHighlight) {
        self.linkAttributeHighlight = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: FRHyperLabelLinkColorHighlight,
                                        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};
    }
}
```

And you can just remove this

```
NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
```

from the attributes

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This library does exactly what the OP asks, I have used this in my projects and it works great

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12789471)

Comment: Answer updated with example

Comment: This is the best answer, but how do I change the style of the linked parts of the label ? for example I don't want it underlined.

Comment: to remove underline, just comment lines in FRHyperLabel like this /*NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)*/

Comment: this doesn't work for swift 3

Comment: tap is not working on bottom line(swift 3)

Comment: This particular pod is out of date. Would love to know any other alternatives.

Comment: This label not working in swift 4. Any update of thid label ?

Answer (score 15):

What you want to do is use an attributed string with a text view to make a link that will act as a button.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some string with link", attributes: [<attributes>])
```

Then set a part of it as a link, and customize it's appearance using the `linkAttributes` property of the Text View. Because this is a button and not an actual link we just put a dummy url in for the link so we can handle it in our delegate later.

```
attributedString.setSubstringAsLink(substring: "link", linkURL: "CUSTOM://WHATEVER")
let linkAttributes: [String : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : .redColor(), NSUnderlineColorAttributeName : .redColor(), NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue]
textView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes
textView.attributedText = attributedString
textView.selectable = true
textView.editable = false
textView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Finally in text view delegate we will check for the scheme and perform some action.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    if URL.scheme == "CUSTOM" {
       // Do your button actions here
    }
    return true
}
```

Extension for setSubstringAsLink:

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    // Set part of string as URL
    public func setSubstringAsLink(substring substring: String, linkURL: String) -> Bool {
        let range = self.mutableString.rangeOfString(substring)
        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            self.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: linkURL, range: range)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: setSubstringAsLink doesn't exist in whole ios library, this is weird, anybody tried this?

Comment: also, this will require a long tap, which is not good for all cases :(

Comment: Edited with an extension for setting the substring. It does not require a long press.

Comment: I'm getting "Result of call to 'setSubstringAsLink(substring:linkURL:) is unused and therefor shouldInteractWithURL is not being fired.

Comment: This has some side effects. When the link is long pressed it show link text over UITextView which seems to be a UIKit native feature.

Answer (score 11):

Let's say you have a `UILabel` with text "**abc**123", and you want "**abc**" to function as a `UIButton`.

- Calculate and store the rectangle that contains "abc".
- Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UILabel`.
- When the `UILabel`is tapped, check if the tap is within the rectangle.

---

```
static func getRect(str: NSAttributedString, range: NSRange, maxWidth: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: str)
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()       
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)     
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0       
    let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSRange>.alloc(1)
    layoutManager.characterRangeForGlyphRange(range, actualGlyphRange: pointer)     
    return layoutManager.boundingRectForGlyphRange(pointer.move(), inTextContainer: textContainer)
}

let rect1 = getRect(label.attributedText!, range: NSMakeRange(0, 3), maxWidth: label.frame.width)

label.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyClass.tappedLabel(_:))))

func tappedLabel(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if rect1.contains(sender.locationInView(sender.view)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: the calculations are off, it only recognizes above the wanted letters !

Comment: @DeyaEldeen Works fine for me. You probably did something wrong.

Comment: what about text coloring?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to use library such as [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/) and using it this way :

Consider the following string "I want to be touchable **here**" where **here** will perform a segue on touch.

- Create `TTTAttributedLabel` (`UILabel` subclass), and put text content in it, as if it was a `UILabel`. Set its delegate to self. Then, add a link to a word this way :

> Objective C

```
NSRange rangeWord = [attributedLabel.text rangeOfString:@"here"];
[attributedLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"anActionOnClickHere"] withRange:rangeUser];
```

> Swift

```
NSRange rangeWord = attributedLabel.text.rangeOfString("here")
attributedLabel.addLinkToURL(NSURL(string: "anActionOnClickHere"), withRange:rangeUser)
```

- On clicking words it will call this method in which you can handle the click :

> Objective C

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(__unused TTTAttributedLabel *)label
   didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSString *urlToString = [url absoluteString];

    if ([urlToString containsString:@"anActionOnClickHere"]) { //perform segue for example
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hereSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

> Swift

```
func attributedLabel(label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didSelectLinkWithURL url: NSURL!) {
    NSString *urlToString = url.absoluteString()
    if (urlToString.containsString("anActionOnClickHere")) { //perform segue for example 
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("hereSegue",sender:self)
    } 
}
```

With the default link style, you'll get the blue color that you're looking for.