# Formatting issue with supporting text with multiple inline buttons in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Does anyone know if there is any alternative to doing what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942812/turn-some-parts-of-uilabel-to-act-like-a-uibutton) asks in SwiftUI? Apparently, NSAttributedStrings are not currently supported, and the library that the accepted answer references ([FRHyperLabel](https://github.com/null09264/FRHyperLabel)) is now outdated and does not work for SwiftUI and Swift 5 (or Swift 4, or Swift 3...). I pretty much need the exact functionality that the linked question asked for – that is, the ability to support text with multiple inline buttons, the amount of which vary in different situations. Any ideas?

EDIT: Okay, I'm now about 90% of the way there. This is definitely not an elegant solution (and it still has its issues anyway), so I welcome any suggestions on how to optimize it.

I wrote this code (xcode 11.7, ios 13):

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct StackoverflowExample: View {
    var body: some View {
        formattedUsingStruct(raw: "Lorem ipsum _dolor_ sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et _dolore_ magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure _dolor_ in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum _dolore_ eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", buttonText: "dolor")
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .font(.system(.body, design: .serif))
                .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
    // this generates the example that does not work (separated vertically)
    private func formattedUsingStruct(raw: String, buttonText: String) -> some View {
        // label, b or t (button or text), i or n (italic or not)
        var labels: [Label] = []
        let tokens = raw.components(separatedBy: "_")
        for (index, token) in tokens.enumerated() {
            if index % 2 != 0 { // italic
                if token == buttonText {
                    labels.append(Label(text: token, style: "b", italic: true))
                } else {
                    labels.append(Label(text: token, style: "t", italic: true))
                }
            } else {
                labels.append(Label(text: token, style: "t", italic: false))
            }
        }
        
        return VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) { // the VStack is what is causing the problem. But I don't know what to use in place of it.
            ForEach(labels) { label in
                if label.style == "t" {
                    self.getText(with: label)
                } else {
                    self.getButton(with: label)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func getButton(with label: Label) -> Button<Text> {
        if label.italic {
            return Button(action: { }, label: { Text(label.text).italic().foregroundColor(.blue) })
        } else {
            return Button(action: { }, label: { Text(label.text).foregroundColor(.blue) })
        }
    }
    
    private func getText(with label: Label) -> Text {
        if label.italic {
            return Text(label.text).italic()
        } else {
            return Text(label.text)
        }
    }
    
    // this generates the example that does work (everything is inline). However, buttons are not supported (just blue text instead).
    private func formatted(raw: String, buttonText: String) -> Text {
        var texts: [Text] = []
        let tokens = raw.components(separatedBy: "_")
        for (index, token) in tokens.enumerated() {
            if index % 2 != 0 { // italic
                if token == buttonText {
                    texts.append(Text(token).italic().foregroundColor(.blue)) // TODO: - add button functionality to click on food and get short description
                } else {
                    texts.append((Text(token).italic()))
                }
            } else {
                texts.append(Text(token))
            }
        }
        return texts.reduce(Text(""), +)
    }
}

struct Label: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var style: String
    var italic: Bool
}

struct StackoverflowExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StackoverflowExample()
    }
}
```

Essentially, the code italicizes every instance of either "dolor" or "dolore" (surrounded with the "_" character in the raw text) and then turns the "dolor"s into a button as well. Running it gives me this:

[image]

However, I would like all the text and buttons to be in-line with each other, like this (generated using the formatted() method, but buttons are not supported).

[image]

I have identified the problem to be the fact that I am returning a VStack in the formattedWithStruct() method. I only did this temporarily, because I wasn't sure what to return if it wasn't a VStack, HStack, or ZStack. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How did you try by your own code?

Comment: @Asperi I added my current progress. Almost there, just struggling with a formatting issue. Thoughts?